# Mapping encapsulated complex types with JMapper

Tags: java, mapping, object-object-mapping

I am trying to map two structures with JMapper but struggle with two encapsulated complex types and how to map them. I want to achive the following:

Source > Destination

Source.sourceString > Destination.destinationString

Source.SourceInternal > Destination.DestinationInternal

Source.SourceInternal.internalString2 > Destination.DestinationInternal.internalString

My classes look as follows:

```java
public class Source {

    private String sourceString;
    private SourceInternal sourceInternal;

    public String getSourceString() {
        return sourceString;
    }

    public void setSourceString(final String sourceString) {
        this.sourceString = sourceString;
    }

    public SourceInternal getSourceInternal() {
        return sourceInternal;
    }

    public void setSourceInternal(final SourceInternal sourceInternal) {
        this.sourceInternal = sourceInternal;
    }

}
```

The internal source object

```java
public class SourceInternal {

    private String internalString1;
    private String internalString2;

    public String getInternalString1() {
        return internalString1;
    }

    public void setInternalString1(final String internalString1) {
        this.internalString1 = internalString1;
    }

    public String getInternalString2() {
        return internalString2;
    }

    public void setInternalString2(final String internalString2) {
        this.internalString2 = internalString2;
    }

}
```

The destination the source should be mapped to

```java
public class Destination {

    private String destinationString;
    private DestinationInternal destinationInternal;

    public String getDestinationString() {
        return destinationString;
    }

    public void setDestinationString(final String destinationString) {
        this.destinationString = destinationString;
    }

    public DestinationInternal getDestinationInternal() {
        return destinationInternal;
    }

    public void setDestinationInternal(final DestinationInternal destinationInternal) {
        this.destinationInternal = destinationInternal;
    }

}
```

The internal destination object.

```java
public class DestinationInternal {

    private String internalString;

    public String getInternalString() {
        return internalString;
    }

    public void setInternalString(final String internalString) {
        this.internalString = internalString;
    }

}
```

How would I achive the described mapping? Is it even possible with JMapper? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into that a similar feature too. Here's how I managed it.

```
        JMapperAPI jMapperAPI = new JMapperAPI()
            .add(mappedClass(Destination.class)
                    .add(attribute("destinationString").value("sourceString"))
                    .add(attribute("destinationInternal").value("sourceInternal")))
            .add(mappedClass(DestinationInternal.class).add(attribute("internalString").value("internalString1").targetClasses(SourceInternal.class)));
```

Basically the logic is to have a mapping for each nested class.